# Wrap long python strings correctly for optparse

Tags: python, string, optparse

How can I automatically wrap long python strings so that they print correctly?

Specifically, I am trying to add help strings with optparse which I want to be able to modify easily.

I have found several methods of dealing with long strings, none of which allow me to refill after making changes using M-q in emacs or similar:

```
p.add_option('-a', help = "this is my\
                           long help text")
```

forces newlines in the result and doesn't allow refilling

```
p.add_option('-a', help = "this is my "
                          "long help text")
```

formats correctly but doesn't allow refilling

```
p.add_option('-a', help = '''
             this is my
             long help text
             ''')
```

formats incorrectly but does allow refilling

```
p.add_option('-a', help = dedent('''
             this is my
             long help text
             '''))
```

is the best option I've found, formats *almost* correctly and allows refilling but results in an additional space at the beginning of the string.

Comment: What is `"refilling"` .. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I am not sure if the terminology is perfect, I am just referring to filling text which was already filled before edits, I took the term from [refill-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RefillMode).

Comment: yeah, but what does "filling text" mean?

Comment: Reformatting the text so that it fits within the chosen column limit, usually 72 or 80 chars by default. Selecting text and hitting M-q performs this in emacs.

Comment: Ahh, that's what refilling means.  I see.  interesting operation.  I'm pretty sure that I wouldn't even attempt to do something like that in a whitespace significant language.

Comment: I suppose that's probably because I'm new to python and spend most of my time in C++, I shall see how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead of optparse, if you are using Python >= 2.7.  It does `dedent` for you.  You can just do:

```
parser.add_argument('--argument', '-a', help='''
    this is my
    long help text
    ''')
```

Even if you are using Python < 2.7, you can install argparse from pypi.

Note that there is a way to suppress this auto-dedent behavior.  The link given by @msw is actually the section about it.

Comment: This is perfect! I wasn't aware that optparse is deprecated. Much better formatting in the help output too.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs use dedent](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#formatter-class) so it seems reasonable, especially if it works. If you want to drop the leading space you could:

```
help = dedent('''
             this is my
             long help text
             ''')[1:]
```

although

```
dedent(…).lstrip()
```

might be more obvious.

Comment: Great, this works really well. From the link I am now using a ``\`` after the inital `'''` instead of the `[1:]` which gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what refilling is, but here's what I typically use:

```
p.add_option('-a', help = ("this is my "
                           "long help text"))
```

(note the additional parenthesis).  Emacs lines up the next line with the previous open parenthesis for me.

Comment: I like that emacs sorts out the tab alignment properly with this method, unfortunately it still can't be filled with M-q.